# Tinting a gradient button background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Create a grey scaled gradient button background xml file?
2. Tinting it in the layout with any color, so that the button gets this color as gradient based on the grey scaling of the background file.

I tried it with `android:backgroundTint`. Unfortunately it tints the whole button in this color without regarding the gradient of the background xml file.

Is there any way to reach my goal by varying this approach?